# Lein uberjar runs repl, not my application

Tags: clojure, leiningen, uberjar

I have a Clojure/Ring/Clojurescript project that I deploy with `lein uberjar`, then launch it with `java -jar whatever-0.1-standalone.jar`. Until recently, it was working fine.

Now when I launch it, I'm presented with a REPL, like this;

`Clojure 1.7.0
user=>`

Thinking it must be something in my code base, I've reverted (with git) to a state I know used to work, but the problem still occurs.

As the problem's not in my codebase, I tried an older version of leiningen - still no luck.

Here's my project.clj:

```
(defproject acfe "0.5"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
                        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[compojure "1.4.0"]
                                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-3308"]
                                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]
                                 [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.32"]
                                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.4.1"]
                                 [yesql "0.4.2"]
                                 [ring "1.4.0"]
                                 [ring-basic-authentication "1.0.5"]
                                 [bk/ring-gzip "0.1.1"]
                                 [prismatic/dommy "1.1.0"]
                                 [enlive "1.1.6"]
                                 [cljs-ajax "0.3.13"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.9.6"]
                        [lein-cljsbuild "1.0.6"]]
  :ring {:handler acfe.core/app
                 :port 3001}
  :cljsbuild
  {:builds
   {:app
        {:source-paths ["src-cljs"]
         :compiler
         {:optimizations :simple
          :output-to "resources/public/js/out/app.js"
          :pretty-print true}}}})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you were actually building the jar with `lein uberjar` before, when it was working? You have no main namespace, instead depending on the `lein-ring` plugin to fabricate one for you, which means you should be running `lein ring uberjar` instead.

Comment: That's it, thank you! I had forgotten which command to run, `lein ring uberjar` works beautifully.

Comment: Thank you! I just ran into this same problem!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a `:main` namespace in project.clj, leiningen (recent versions at least) will default to clojure.main. If you uncompress the jar file and look inside `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, you can check. You'll see a line that looks like this:

`Main-Class: clojure.main`

Add a mapping like this to set the main class:

`:main whatever.core` (assuming you want the `-main` function in that namespace).